# How to set a group of radio button disabled based on condition

Tags: jquery

I have a group of radio buttons and I want to set them disabled if their value is greater or equal to another value.

Here is the code I am trying to use:

```
$('input[type=radio][name="motor_hp"]').change(function(){
  var value = parseFloat($(this).val()).toFixed(1);
  console.log(value);
  $('input[name="ics-drive"]').filter(function(){
    console.log($(this).val());
    return parseFloat($(this).attr('value')).toFixed(1) >= value;
  }).prop("disabled",true);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `.filter()` function between the parenthesis... You have to return an element.

Try this:

```
$('input[type=radio][name="motor_hp"]').change(function(){
  var value = parseFloat($(this).val()).toFixed(1);
  console.log(value);
  $('input[name="ics-drive"]').filter(function(){

    console.log($(this).val());
    if(parseFloat($(this).val()).toFixed(1) >= value){
      return $(this);
    }

  }).prop("disabled",true);
})
```

Comment: Sir these solution not working //if moto_ hp selected then drive details hp >= motor_hp
    $('input[type=radio][name="motor_hp"]').change(function(){
     var value = parseFloat($(this).val()).toFixed(1);
     $('input[name="ics_drive"]').filter(function(){

      console.log($(this).val());
      if(parseFloat($(this).val()).toFixed(1) < value){
       return $(this);
      }

     }).prop("disabled",true);
    })

Comment: filter method return only true or false

Comment: $('input[name="ics_drive"]').each(function(i,v){
      var chk_value = parseFloat($(this).val()).toFixed(1); 
      if (chk_value < value){
       console.log(chk_value < value);
       $(this).prop("disabled",true);

      }
     })

Comment: I can't help you more without your HTML markup. I just don't know what you try to do. Here is a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/EegOOZ?editors=1010) showing that my solution works.